# gradle runJar task?

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to make a task to run my Jar file in gradle.

I have come up with the following:

```
task runJar(dependsOn:[jar]){
  ant.java(jar:,fork:true)
}
```

However, I am unable to find the path to the jar file. Any help much appreciated. Thank you!

Misha

EDIT: OK this is rather odd. This task runs *before* compile, etc.???

EDIT: Fixed. The key is in a doLast { } notation, or, in shorthand

```
task runJar(dependsOn:"jar")<<{
  ant.java(jar:"${libsDir}${File.separator}${archivesBaseName}.jar",fork:true)
}
```

Misha

Answer (score 9):

Koppor's answer works perfectly.

With a Main.java in src/main/java, my build.gradle file looks like

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "Main"
```

Running it gives:

```
gradle run                 

:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:run
[Main.java's output]
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the [The Application Plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)? It creates a new task "run", which runs the specified java class.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the jar.archivePath variable ;

```
task runJar(dependsOn:[jar]){
  ant.java(jar: jar.archivePath ,fork:true)
}
```

Comment: How do I provide **args** here?

Comment: Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033853/how-to-pass-arguments-to-ant-java-method-in-groovy

Answer (score 1):

My best solution so far:

```
task runJar(dependsOn:[jar]){
  ant.java(jar:"${libsDir}${File.separator}${archivesBaseName}.jar",fork:true)
}
```

Thank you!

Misha

Comment: Hi! I've tried your solution, but I have no output from the jar - I only get a Java Result: 1 information, though a I have wrtitten to `System.out` in my `main` method... How do I get the output?

Comment: I need to provide **args**.