# How to pass arguments to ant.java() method in Groovy

Tags: groovy, antbuilder

I am trying to convert an ant `<java>` task to groovy. I am using the following code:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder();
ant.java(classpath:'jar_file_path', classname:'Main', fork:'true')
```

I also have a list of command line arguments to be passed to the method.

- Q1. How should I pass the command line arguments to the method in groovy?
- Q2. Any documentation on groovy which can get me started quickly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder();
ant.java(classpath:'jar_file_path', classname:'Main', fork:'true') {
  arg( value: 'arg 1' )
}
```

As for learning Groovy, the second edition of [groovy in action](http://www.manning.com/koenig2/) is available as a early access ebook